# sum of the digits of the number $(5^{2015})(2^{2018})$

Tags: exponentiation

What is the sum of the digits of the number $(5^{2015})(2^{2018})$

So I am guessing, I have to find out the product of $(5^{2015})(2^{2018})$ and add each digit of the product.

The question is how do I find the product of $(5^{2015})(2^{2018})$. Both numbers don't share the same base or exponents, so none of the laws of exponents (that I know of) will help me. Unless this problem is meant to be clever and have another way.

Any leads?

Comment: Notice that $5^x\cdot2^x=10^x$. Does this help?

Comment: Note that $5^{2015} \times 2^{2018}$ = $(2\times 5)^{2015} \times 2^3 $.

Comment: @dmtri: This is what I meant with "avoid gaming the system". If you feel the need to edit old questions, find the ones that *really* need to be edited. Not just capitalisations of "i" or adding `$` around `p`. The older the thread, the more substantial the edit should be.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila,  thanks for making the point.  I will follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(5^{2015})(2^{2018}) = (5^{2015})(2^{2015})(2^3) = (5\cdot 2)^{2015}2^3$$
$$= 10^{2015}2^3 = 8\cdot 10^{2015}$$
Notice that this is just the digit $8$ followed by $2015$ zeroes, so the sum is just $8$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $(5)^{2015}(2)^{2015} = (10)^{2015}$.

$(2)^{2018} = 2^{2015} \cdot 2^3$